# Printing out box drawing characters (extended-ascii, unicode) on c++ console

Tags: c++, unicode, character, ascii

I'm attempting to draw a box using box drawing characters (┌─┐└─┘ something like these characters).
I'm not sure if this helps but I'm using a Korean computer, and these characters print out just fine on my computer, even just with cout.
However, on the school computer, it does not print out normally, but some weird letters that I can't even recognize.

I've researched a lot, and got some advices saying that I have to use wcout, or use wchar_t or something in order to print unicode characters;

My question is, is there a simple way to print those characters on vs c++ console?
This is not a serious and big project so it being unstable, and not being compatible with other system would be fine. It just has to work on Windows.

I know I'm supposed to upload some progress, but I really couldn't figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `wcout` and `wchar_t` strings with the relevant box drawing unicode chars? You should show how you are printing the chars with `cout` on your home computer

Comment: What operating system does the school computer use? Is it using UTF-8?